# Work with list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
list = [
    {'album': '1', 'artist': 'pedro', 'title': 'Duhast'},
    {'album': '2', 'artist': 'hose', 'title':'Star boy'},
    {'album': '1', 'artist': 'migel', 'title': 'Lemon tree'}
]
```

I need to group/sort this list like this :

```
list = [
    {'album': '1', 
     'tracks': [
        {'artist': 'pedro', 'title': 'Duhast'},
        {'artist': 'migel', 'title': 'Lemon tree'}]
    },
    {'album': '2',
     'tracks':[
        {'artist': 'hose', 'title':'Star boy'}]
    }
]
```

More precisely, I need to group tracks by albums. Any ideas to make this easy?

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working for you?  We generally expect you to work out some code on your own, before asking for help.

Comment: While you're doing that, look into the **groupby** function.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-liner :)

```
from itertools import groupby

list = [{'album': '1', 'artist': 'pedro', 'title': 'Duhast'}, {'album': '2', 'artist': 'hose', 'title':'Star boy'}, {'album': '1', 'artist': 'migel', 'title': 'Lemon tree'}]

res = [{'album': album, 'tracks': [{'artist': track['artist'], 'title': track['title']} for track in tracks]} for album, tracks in groupby(sorted(list, key=lambda x: x['album']), lambda x: x['album'])]

print(res)
```

https://repl.it/HA48/2

As @Prune mentioned, the `groupby` function can be used to group a list by a specified key function.  In order for this to work, the list must be sorted by the key.

Personally, I find the above solution a little hard to read... This gives the same result:

```
from itertools import groupby

list = [{'album': '1', 'artist': 'pedro', 'title': 'Duhast'}, {'album': '2', 'artist': 'hose', 'title':'Star boy'}, {'album': '1', 'artist': 'migel', 'title': 'Lemon tree'}]

res = []
for album, tracks in groupby(sorted(list, key=lambda x: x['album']), lambda x: x['album']):
  res.append({'album': album, 'tracks': [{'artist': track['artist'], 'title': track['title']} for track in tracks]})

print(res)
```

https://repl.it/HA48/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are simply the god of programming